# Dynamic LINQ on a generic object (without any hard-coded properties)

Tags: c#, linq, generics, dynamic-linq

I have a generic object which uses a dictionary to store the properties:

```
class MyObject 
{
    Dictionary<string, object> Properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    internal GetValue(string name) { return Properties[name]; }
    internal SetValue(string name, object value) { Properties[name] = value; } 
}
MyObject obj1 = New MyObject();
obj1.SetValue("Name", "John");
obj1.SetValue("Age", 23);

MyObject obj2 = New MyObject();
obj2.SetValue("Name", "Mary");
obj2.SetValue("Age", 24);

List<MyObject> ObjList = new List<MyObject>();
ObjList.Add(obj1);
ObjList.Add(obj2);
```

Now we need to query the ObjList to find certain entries. Dynamic LINQ (*[Dynamic LINQ (Part 1: Using the LINQ Dynamic Query Library)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)*) seems to be perfect, but from what I can see it requires that the object have pre-defined properties.

We want to do queries like:

```
ObjList.Where("Name == 'Mary' || Age < 24");
```

Any token (e.g. Name, Age) should call "GetValue". Any suggestions?

Obviously the where statement is completely up to the user and is not fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# 4.0 you could have your `MyObject` implement the `IDynamicMetaDataProvider` interface so that property tokens get resolved to GetValue() and SetValue() respectively. Dynamic LINQ should then work as expected.

See [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/ff800651.aspx) for an example

Comment: Wow, thanks for the hint. Actually looks like I might use an ExpandoObject instead!

Answer (score 1):

The source for the Dynamic LINQ extension method Where clause is:

```
public static IQueryable Where(this IQueryable source, string predicate, params object[] values) {
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (predicate == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("predicate");
    LambdaExpression lambda = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(source.ElementType, typeof(bool), predicate, values);
    return source.Provider.CreateQuery(
        Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable), "Where",
            new Type[] { source.ElementType },
            source.Expression, Expression.Quote(lambda)));
}
```

The complicated part is the DynamicExpression.ParseLambda bit. A very quick look through the source shows that the parsing code includes a "ParseMemberAccess" function which seems to suggest that you might be able to do something like:

```
ObjList.Where("GetValue('Name') == 'Mary' || GetValue('Age') < 24");
```

And, if the parser doesn't currently allow that, you could easily extend it so that it does.